# Deserialization using JsonConvert

Tags: c#, .net, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

I am trying to write a method which will accept a JSON string and Type. The aim of the method is to deserialize the string in the object specified by the type. I want the code to look like something below

```
public dynamic Deserialize(string serializedStr, Type type) {
      return JsonConvert.Deserialize<type>(serializedStr);
 }
```

Is it possible do such an operation using Newtonsoft.JSon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is:

```
public dynamic Deserialize(string serializedStr, Type type)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serializedStr, type);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

create a generic method like this:

```
public T DeserializeObject<T>(string serializedStr)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serializedStr);
}
```

Comment: He seems to have the Type instance only. That means he would only be able to use a generic method using reflection. Besides, why no just call the Json method directly?

Answer (score 1):

here's a little example of a helper extension method static class to serve both sides (needs scoping etc if going into prod):

```
public static class JsonHelpers
{
    public static T DeserializeObject<T>(this string jsonString)
    {
        try
        {
            var concreteObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString);
            return concreteObject;
        }
        catch
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
    public static string SerializeObject<T>(this T concreteObject)
    {
        try
        {
            var jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(concreteObject);
            return jsonString;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

`var jsonString = yourclass.SerializeObject();`

`var classObject = serialisedString.DeserializeObject<yourClass>();`